# load_icon() function for glfwSetWindowIcon()?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am trying to set the window icon for my glfw window but I don't know how to set an icon using GLFWimage.

The code in the docs is as shown:

```
GLFWimage images[2];
images[0] = load_icon("my_icon.png");
images[1] = load_icon("my_icon_small.png");
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 2, images);
```

But it doesn't show how to use or create a "load_icon" function.
So, can anyone help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
glfwSetWindowIcon(GLFWwindow * window, int count, const GLFWimage * images)
```

I think the first two parameters are clear and there is the third, `GLFWimage` which is a structure with fields `int width, int height, unsigned char * pixels` but its your task to provide data for it, GLFW does not give you functions to load your images but there are several libraries which does or you can write your own function to get image data.

I'm not really c++ guy so I'm not aware of the newest/best libraries currently but there is soil for example which would work just fine. Something like this:

```
GLFWimage icons[1];
icons[0].pixels = SOIL_load_image("icon.png", &icons[0].width, &icons[0].height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
glfwSetWindowIcon(window.window, 1, icons);
SOIL_free_image_data(icons[0].pixels);
```

Comment: If you are using stb_image.h, this is the code you should be using: GLFWimage images[1];

images[0].pixels = stbi_load("PATH", &images[0].width, &images[0].height, 0, 4); //rgba channels
 
 glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, images);
 stbi_image_free(images[0].pixels);

Comment: Dude, make this an answer.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using "stb_image.h", this is the code you should be using:

```
GLFWimage images[1]; 
images[0].pixels = stbi_load("PATH", &images[0].width, &images[0].height, 0, 4); //rgba channels 
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, images); 
stbi_image_free(images[0].pixels);
```