# How does GLFWimage manage data?

Tags: c++, class, glfw, soil

I found this topic:
[GLFW SetWindowIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321902/glfw-setwindowicon)
It got me wondering how does class GLFWimage manage its char* pixels. Class itself doesn't have a constructor so it can't itself create array holding picture data. Ofc I can just copy pointer to precreated array of data, but example in the topic is supposed to free data after loading it. My guess is glfwSetWindowIcon just copies data from GLFWimage pointer. To be fair I don't see what is being freed as icons[0].pixels is just getting pointer from a function. I wrote myself class that loads image. I set value of GLFWimage to data inside this class. Than I called: glfwSetWindowIcon. Then I changed data inside. Icon stays on the menu bar and on the top bar of the window. It gets me even more confusing as there are so many contradictory answers about freeing data in opengl. 
Here is the class I wrote. Keep in mind the file sent to its constructor has to be pre stripped to raw data:

```
class icon_gl{
public:
int width;
int height;
unsigned char * pixels;
bool failed;
int file_size;

icon_gl(int set_width, int set_height, string name){
    width = set_width;
    height = set_height;
    failed = 1;
    pixels = new unsigned char[set_width*set_height*4];
    ifstream file(name.c_str(), ios::binary);
    if(file.is_open()){
        file.seekg(0, ios::end);
        file_size = file.tellg();
    }
    if(file_size == set_width*set_height*4){
        failed =0;
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read((char*)pixels, set_width*set_height*4);
    }
}
~icon_gl(){
    delete[] pixels;
}
void import(GLFWimage * img_gl){
    img_gl->width=width;
    img_gl->height=height;
    img_gl->pixels = pixels;
}
};
```

Here is main:

```
icon_gl icon32(32, 32, "iconimage.i");
GLFWimage ico_image;
icon32.import(&ico_image);
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, &ico_image);
```

And a&& behavior:

```
for (int i=0; i<32*32*4; i++)icon32.pixels[i] = 255;
```

Questions: How does opengl manages its data? Maybe you could give me some good links? I am looking for the entire scope rather than single case. How does SOIL_free_image_data work? Is it just mistake or does it somewhow edit the pointer parameters(length of data)? Shouldnt managing poiner's length of data belong to compilator scope of work?

Comment: Came to my mind it can be connected with malloc/alloc and free instead of reserving data through new.

Comment: If you want to take a look at GLFW code, here is the [Git link](https://github.com/glfw/glfw)

Comment: For starting wit OpenGL read [this book](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/) or many others tutorials on the web.