# Cannot set Window Icon in GLFW C++ Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019, glfw

**I've tried to set the window icon from the scripts within the stackoverflow questions below, but nothing did work to my solution**

[GLFW SetWindowIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321902/glfw-setwindowicon)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-icons

My entire main.cpp from my solution:

```
#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "imgui/imgui_impl_glfw.h"
#include "imgui/imgui_impl_opengl3.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>
#include <WinNls32.h>


int main()
{
// Create a custom icon at run time.
// Initialize GLFW
glfwInit();

// Tell GLFW what version of OpenGL we are using 
// In this case we are using OpenGL 3.3
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
// Tell GLFW we are using the CORE profile
// So that means we only have the modern functions
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Create a GLFWwindow object of 800 by 800 pixels, naming it "YoutubeOpenGL"
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1200, 700, "Dessor 0.1.0c", NULL, NULL);
// Error check if the window fails to create
if (window == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
// Introduce the window into the current context
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

//Load GLAD so it configures OpenGL
gladLoadGL();
// Specify the viewport of OpenGL in the Window
// In this case the viewport goes from x = 0, y = 0, to x = 800, y = 800
glViewport(0, 0, 1200, 700);



// Initialize ImGUI
IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
ImGui::CreateContext();
ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL(window, true);
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init("#version 330");

// Variables to be changed in the ImGUI window
bool drawCube = false;
float size = 1.0f;
float color[4] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };


// Main while loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    // Specify the color of the background
    glClearColor(0.11f, 0.11f, 0.11f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Clean the back buffer and assign the new color to it

    // Tell OpenGL a new frame is about to begin
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
    ImGui::NewFrame();

    if (drawCube)
        glClearColor(0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // ImGUI window creation
    // Particular widget styling
    static int i2 = 3;
    static int ifov = 60;
    static float size = 3.0;
    static char name[128] = "5";
    static const ImVec4 edge_color = ImVec4(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.90f, 1.00f);
    static const ImVec4 inside_color = ImVec4(0.55f, 0.55f, 0.90f, 1.00f);
    const ImVec2 size2 = ImVec2(250, 200);

    ImGui::PushStyleColor(ImGuiCol_Text, IM_COL32(255, 0, 0, 255));
    ImGui::Begin("Drawing HyperCube Options", NULL, ImGuiWindowFlags_AlwaysAutoResize);
    ImGui::PopStyleColor();
    ImGui::Checkbox("Draw Shape", &drawCube);
    ImGui::SliderInt("D", &i2, 0, atoi(name), "%d-dimensional hypercube");
    ImGui::InputText("", name, 7, ImGuiInputTextFlags_CharsDecimal | ImGuiInputTextFlags_EnterReturnsTrue);
    ImGui::SameLine();
    ImGui::TextColored(ImVec4(255, 0, 255, 255), name);
    ImGui::NewLine();
    ImGui::SliderFloat("SIZE", &size, 1.0, 10.0);
    ImGui::SliderInt("FOV", &ifov, 30, 120, "%d");
    ImGui::NewLine();
    ImGui::Button("Render", ImVec2(250, 60));
    ImGui::BeginChild("Inside color", size2);
    ImGui::TextColored(inside_color, "INSIDE COLOR");
    ImGui::ColorPicker3("", (float*)&inside_color);
    ImGui::TextColored(edge_color, "EDGE COLOR");
    ImGui::ColorEdit3("", (float*)&edge_color);
    ImGui::EndChild();
    ImGui::NewLine();
    ImGui::End();
    // Checkbox that appears in the window

    // Renders the ImGUI elements
    ImGui::Render();
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

    // Swap the back buffer with the front buffer
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    // Take care of all GLFW events
    glfwPollEvents();
}

// Deletes all ImGUI instances
ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Shutdown();
ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown();
ImGui::DestroyContext();

// Delete window before ending the program
glfwDestroyWindow(window);
// Terminate GLFW before ending the program
glfwTerminate();
return 0;
}
```

How can I use the `glfwSetWindowIcon()` or there's another way for change window icon in native c++?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GLFW SetWindowIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321902/glfw-setwindowicon)

Comment: In the code you've shown there is no sight of the icon loading process, maybe you should be more specific? The _glfwSetWindowIcon()_ function should work so did you load your data correctly?